# Wireless interface Authorization supplicant failed kubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, kubuntu, iwlwifi

I installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my brand new machine MSI MEG X570 ACE motherboard with Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX 200 n/w card. 
There is no Windows installed no double booting only Kubuntu. 
When I try to connect to my home wifi I get following error. How can I fix this?
[image]

kernel specs:

```
Linux jarvis 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
richie@jarvis:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ uname -r
5.4.0-29-generic
richie@jarvis:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$
```

lshw -C network and iwconfig output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I believe I found the solution. I had to change the power saving settings for NetworkManager:

```
sudoedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Change the number 3 to a 2.